# Jquery Slider - prevent double click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem with slider. Whenever i spam the arrow to change pictures, it might show more than a one image. It should display always 4 images, so one should dissapear and one appear.

```
$('.ranks_user_badges').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
     var slider = $(this);
     var caniclick = true;

     $(this).find('.ranks_controls_right').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var first_visible = $(slider).find('li:visible:first');
        var last_visible = $(slider).find('li:visible:last');

        var count = $(slider).find('li:visible').length + last_visible.next().length;
        if(count > 4 && caniclick === true){
            caniclick = false;

            first_visible.hide(500);
            last_visible.next().show(500);

            setTimeout(function(){
                caniclick = true;
            }, 500);
        }

         });});
```

I've tried with timeouts, no animation time - nothing really works :/

Comment: 1) Can you post a fiddle?
2) What does that got to do with prevent double clcik?
3) If you want to listen to the double click event, try .dblclick()

Comment: did you tried inversing the order of : e.preventDefault();        e.stopPropagation();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `var caniclick = true;` outside of `$('.ranks_user_badges').click(function(e){`

This should do the trick